# get the first and the 2nd and the last element in array python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice, array-algorithms

hi my question is very simple
i have array like this

list=[3,2,4,1]

i want to get the first element which is --> 3

and the second element which is --> 2

and the last or fourth element which is --> 1

`output = [3,2,1]` 
also i want the
`output =[3,4,1]`
without using this method

`output=[ list[0],list[2],list[3] ]`

and without using any function or library, just python

i mean using slicing and for loop

also the indices are varying to print all the possible combination

see the code below

```
nums_1=[3,2,4,1]
results=[]
steps=1
s=0
limit=pow(2, len(nums_1))

while steps<=len(nums_1) and s<limit :
    
    for i in range (0,len(nums_1)+1):

            for j in range (0,len(nums_1)+1):

                if nums_1[i:j:steps] not in results:

                            results.append(sorted(nums_1[i:j:steps]))
                    
                print(i,j,steps,'--------------->',nums_1[i:j:steps])
    steps+=1 
    s+=1
```

output is
[[], [3], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 4], [1, 2, 4], [4], [1, 4], [1], [3, 4], [1, 2], [1, 3]]

[1,2,3] and [1,3,4] not in the result

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: i know maybe the question is quit easy but its not the full story, and if i tell the story i will have the answer, but i want some hints, therefore answering this question will give me hints thanks for your understanding

Comment: "if i tell the story i will have the answer": that seems like it doesn't make sense. You already know the answer? Then why ask a question?

Comment: No i donot know the answer , the question is a part from a big problem, i need to answer on this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please read this and improve your question :D

Comment: see the edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know which indexes you want to find, you can insert these in a list. Then use list comprehension to generate a new list with the found elements.

```
lst=[3,2,4,1]
indexes = [0,1,-1]
found = [lst[ind] for ind in indexes]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, kindly see the edit above